# i am getting "segmentation fault" while executing this program

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, singly-linked-list

This is a code for implementation of singly linked list in c++.
Three basic operations i.e.,insertion, deletion and display is being performed. The data is passed from the main function. The code getting complied but during execution it shows "Segmentation Fault".
Please tell me what is wrong with the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class list
{
    private:
        typedef struct node
        {
            int data;`
            node* next;
        }* nodeptr;
        nodeptr head;
        nodeptr curr;
        nodeptr temp;
    public:
        list();
        void insert(int addData);
        void delet(int delData);
        void display();
};
list::list()
{
    head=NULL;
    curr=NULL;
    temp=NULL;
}
void list::insert(int addData)
{
    nodeptr n=new node;
    n->next=NULL;
    n->data=addData;
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        curr=head;
        while(curr!=NULL)
        {
            curr=curr->next;
        }
        curr->next=n;
    }
        else
    {
        head=n;
    }
}    
void list::delet(int delData)
{
    nodeptr delptr=NULL;
    temp=head;
    curr=head;
    while(curr!=NULL&&curr->data!=delData)
    {
        temp=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    if(curr==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Data not found.";
        delete delptr;
    }
    else
    {
        delptr=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
        temp->next=curr;
        delete delptr;
    }
}
void list::display()
{
    curr=head;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<curr->data;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    list l;
    l.insert(1);
    l.insert(2);
    l.insert(3);
    l.insert(4);
    l.insert(5);
    l.display();
    cout<<"\nDeleting:";
    l.delet(3);
    l.display();
    l.delet(5);
    l.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by compiling with debug information (add the flag `-g` to GCC). Then run your program in the debugger `gdb`, and it will stop where the error is. Use the `bt` command in `gdb` to find the call stack, and edit the question to include it (if you can't figure it out yourself).

Comment: btw, structs is equivalent to class in C++ (default access aside). Use a constructor and destrubtor for `node` for better stability.

Comment: @Bathsheba i used destructor, still its showing "Segmentation fault(core dumped)"

Comment: When you've gotten the list to work, and maybe even worked with a generic type (using templates), then you should promptly throw it away and start using the [C++ standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with insert function:

```
curr=head;

while(curr!=NULL)
{
    curr=curr->next;
}
curr->next=n;
```

After reaching the curr to null you are accessing it. It should be:

```
curr=head;

while(curr->next !=NULL)
{
    curr=curr->next;
}
curr->next=n;
```